# Preferred statistics to evaluate interrater agreement of group of raters (nominal dependent variable, two groups of raters) and compare both groups

Tags: r, categorical-data, agreement-statistics

I hypothesized that a set of symptoms is not really specific to a particular syndrome (let´s say A), so I recruited two groups of experts to classify each symptom (I have 16) to condition A, B, C (which in reality is A+B, "both"), and D (which is neither of A or B). I used Gwet´s AC1 to assess inter-rater agreement of the overall 16 symptoms over each group and ran a paired t-test to evaluate group differences in their ratings (two groups assessing the same set of symptoms).
I am unsure about three issues:

1. to what extent AC1 is the best statistic to analyze these results (raters classifying symptom -a dependent variable with nominal categories).
2. how convenient is to evaluate agreement over each symptom instead of the set of symptoms (I wasn´t able to perform this analysis using both irrCAC and pairedCAC R packages)
3. whether t-test is the right statistic to perform the comparison. I am pretty sure I am wrong b/c there is not really a mean comparison --dependent variable is nominal.
   thanks in advance!
   ,